# Remove certain part of text files with VSCode's regex search & replace

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have hundreds of text files with contents of this type (these are .txt content files from Kirby CMS):

```
Attributes:

- attribute: ''

----

Materials:

- 
  material: ""
  price: 0
  available: 'true'
  default: 'true'
  material_variations:
    - 
      variations:
        - 
          option: 
          variation: —
          price: "0"
          variation_available: 'true'
        - 
          option: 
          variation: ""
          price: "0"
          variation_available: 'true'

----

Price: 0
```

I want to remove the part from `Materials:` to the next `----`, so the above snippet becomes:

```
Attributes:

- attribute: ''

----

Price: 0
```

I am searching for a regular expression to achieve that, but some things that I thought could maybe work (e.g. `\bMaterials\b[^]\b----\b`), produce an error in VSCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[^]` construct only works in the Find and Replace in-document search tool. In the file search tool, Rust regex flavor is used, and `[^]` does not work there.

You can use

```
\bMaterials\b[\w\W]*?----\n*
```

*Details*:

- `\bMaterials\b` - a whole word `Materials`
- `[\w\W]*?` - any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `----` - a literal string of four hyphens
- `\n*` - zero or more line breaks.